# Изменение текущей директории

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, ос

В моей программе использую класс `QProcess` для запуска других приложений. Но вот беда, приложения которые запускаются имеют "текущую директорию" расположение моей программы. Как это исправить?

```
// пример ф-ции для запуска других программ (и закрытии себя)
void MainWindow::runExe(QString pathToExe)
{
    QProcess *process = new QProcess();
    process->start(exe.path() + "/" + pathToExe);
    if (process->waitForStarted())
        close();
    else
        qDebug() << QString("Can't run exe: %1").arg(process->program());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У QProcess есть спецфункция - [setWorkingDirectory](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setWorkingDirectory) - используйте ее, что бы выставить правильную директорию.

Comment: блин, вместо того что бы почитать какие методы есть у класса, начал в интернете искать решение(.. через 8 мин приму ответ